# How can you have VS Code open fullscreen by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a setting to have VS Code open in fullscreen mode by default?

Answer (score 16):

There's a setting to "restore fullscreen". When that setting is turned on, VS Code will open in full screen mode if you exit VS Code in full screen mode:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Open the settings UI (`command-,` on a mac) -> search `restore fullscreen` -> check the `Window: Restore Fullscreen` setting

Answer (score 12):

In `settings.json` add

```
  "window.restoreFullscreen": true
```

Comment: It seems to me that the correct setting should be `"window.newWindowDimensions": "fullscreen",`

Answer (score 12):

The question says "fullscreen" but many users probably mean they want a maximised window that takes up the full screen.

To do this open vscode settings with `Ctrl+,`

Go to `Window` then `New Window`

In `New Window Dimensions` setting choose `Maximised`

setting json is

```json
"window.newWindowDimensions": "maximized"
```